# Why does the Chosen Select DropDown goes under the footer DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I have the following HTML:

```
<!-- HEADER CONTENT -->
<div class="bodyMainContentHolder" style="min-height: 750px;">
    <div class="sectionfp group visOverflow">
            <div class="col span_1_of_3_cust span_pad_right">
                <div class="smallPadTop brClear setLeft">
                    <div class="setBold brClear">Select Language:</div>
                    <div class="chosenDDLHolder">
                        <asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlLanguage" CssClass="chosen-select setProvDDStyle" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- FOOTER CONTENT -->
```

CSS:

```
.chosenDDLHolder {
    width: 100%;
}
.setBold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.setLeft {
    text-align: left;
}
.brClear {
    clear: both;
}
.smallPadTop {
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
}
/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    /*float:left;*/
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
}
.col:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.span_1_of_3_cust {
    width: 28.2%;
}
.span_pad_right {
    padding-right: 1%;
}
.bodyMainContentHolder {
    width: 98%;
    overflow: hidden; /* tried changing this to "overflow: visible" but didn't work */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2% 0 2% 0;
}
.sectionfp {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before, .group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
.group {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}
.visOverflow {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

If the footer is close to the dropdownlist, it gets clipped. The only way to avoid it, is to use the `min-height` style but it creates unnecessary white space.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

How can I modify the code so that the dropdownlist always goes above any other DIV and still stay with the flow of the surrounding DIVs (without using the `absolute` position)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/74/

HTML Source:

[image]

Comment: use [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: I added `z-index` all the way up the chain but still the same :/

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/17/troubleshooting-css/#article-z-index) article, perhaps it will help you, if you struggle with the `z-index`

Comment: Add the `z-index` and position to the entire header `bodyMainContentHolder` and be sure the z-index on footer is lower

Comment: You need to look at the html *after* the select is created.  Don't forget that happens client-side, and your css will need to be relevant to what Chosen has done when it's modified the document.  In particular, look at `.chosen-container`

Comment: @Danko Took your advice but didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Archer I posted the source output and I put z-index and position on every possible tag but nothing is working for me :/

Comment: If you are going to get answer create a jsfiddle.net

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/74/

Comment: Is your `#footerContent`'s `position` set to **`fixed`**, **`absolute`** or **`relative`**?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Reply to my previous comment.

Comment: @cuSK Here is the JSFiddle (not working, just the code to show): http://jsfiddle.net/nrkpqbx6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `overflow: hidden` from the `bodyMainContentHolder`. Your container is hiding the inner drop-down div.

http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/77/

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle (not working, just the code to show): jsfiddle.net/nrkpqbx6

Comment: Is the problem that it is still UNDER the footer, or that it is clipped by the bottom of the viewport?

Comment: Isn't they both the same? The screenshot from the question is still there :/

Comment: Ok well in your original fiddle you didn't include the wrapper around `bodyMainContentHolder`, which looks to be `bodyContent`, which ALSO needs to have its `overflow:hidden` removed.

Comment: I removed both and put `overflow: visible` and still nothing.

Comment: New fiddle then please, include all your output HTML (not the asp tags) and CSS. Include it all.

Comment: How do I add files from local drive in JSFiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64894/discussion-between-josh-kg-and-searchforknowledge).