# Chosen Options Going Under Container

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs-directive, jquery-chosen

I'm using the chosen dropdown library for an angularjs project using the [angular-chosen](https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen) directive.

I'm currently working on implementing a paginated table and I'm having a problem with the dropdown options appearing underneath the container div in my body.

[image: screenshot]

Here is the relevant html

```
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="data-table">
                <div class="data-table-header">
                    <h2>Name - 000111222</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="data-table-content">
                    <table class="table-striped">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>001</td>
                                <td>Test, Test</td>
                                <td>Import Complete</td>
                                <td>10/24/2013 7:27:42</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4" class="pagination">
                                    <div class="page-size">
                                        Page Size:
                                        <select chosen disable-search="true" id="page-size">
                                            <option>10 items</option>
                                            <option>25 items</option>
                                            <option>50 items</option>
                                            <option>100 items</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried commenting out all of my custom css for styling the dropdown and nothing changed in regards to this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: I used firefox's 3d view to take a look and it doesn't seem to be a z-index issue

[image: zindex screenshot]

Comment: If the position property values are both the same, use a higher z-index for. It's not, apply position property value of absolute with a higher z-index.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a z-index issue. I added a new image that will hopefully help.

Comment: This solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/26912462/840635 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add css property `z-index`.

Put your div container under all elements

```
<style>
   .under{
      z-index:-200; //this put your div under other elements
   }
</style>
```

**Don't forget to apply `class="under"` to your div container.**

---

Or you can put your dropdown options over all elements

```
<style>
   .over{
      z-index:200; //this put your dropdown options over other elements
   }
</style>
```

**Don't forget to apply `class="over"` to your dropdown options.**